# zabbix agent active use non-active items

Tags: zabbix

I have several Linux servers behind NAT, and I want to monitor these servers by OS-Linux-Template of zabbix.

Since they are behind NAT, I run zabbix-agent in active mode on them to connect zabbix-server.
However, the items of OS-Linux-Template are all non-active mode, so it seems that the items do not work.

Can the active-mode agent report non-active mode items?

I do not want to use zabbix-proxy because I think it is too heavy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clone the template, then make all items active in the cloned template. You also have to change the LLD rules and item prototypes to active.

There is no way to switch active/passive per host, you have to use a separate template.